# I'm trying to get alt text of an image to appear in a paragraph with event listeners

Tags: javascript

```
var imgHover = document.getElementById("theImg");
imgHover.addEventListener('click', altText(imgHover)); 

function altText(theText)
{
  document.getElementById("alt-text").innerHTML = theText;
}
```

What do I use to refer to an image's alt text through a function?

It gives an error: cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

```
<img src="frozen-kingscreek.jpg" alt="This is nice creek" id="theImg">
<img src="hungry-ravens.jpg" alt="This is nice bird" id="theImg">
<img src="snapping-turtle.jpg" alt="This is nice turtle" id="theImg">

<p id="no"></p>

<script src="script.js"></script>
```

this is my index file

Answer (score 0):

To get an attribute of an HTML element use `getAttribute`

```
element.getAttribute(attributename)
```

Ideally id should be unique, however in your case all img tag has same id.

```
var imgHover = document.getElementById("theImg");
imgHover.addEventListener('click', altText); 

function altText()
{
  document.getElementById("alt-text").innerHTML = this.getAttribute("alt");
}
```

To add click event to all the images which have css class `.example`

```
document.querySelectorAll(".example").forEach(img => {
 img.addEventListener('click', () => { 
   document.getElementById("alt-text").innerHTML = img.getAttribute("alt");
 });
});
```